# Uploading a xml file to ftp server in C#, file has been successfully uploaded but there is no contents in it?

Tags: c#, xml, ftpwebrequest

My problem is that when I view the uploaded file on my ftp server, there is no contents on it, it is empty. Why is this happening am I missing something in my code?

```
if (File.Exists("main.xml"))
{
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        string uri = String.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}/{2}", "host", "wwwroot", "main.xml");

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        request.EnableSsl = false;

        int bufferLength = 2048;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        int contentLength;

        Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        contentLength = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        while (contentLength != 0)
        {
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
            contentLength = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }

        ftpStream.Flush();
        ftpStream.Close();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No file found.");
}
```

But when I try to insert this line of code above

```
MessageBox.Show(XDocument.Load("main.xml").ToString());
```

It has an output,

But when I try setting a breakpoint , when It reach `while (contentLength != 0)` it does not enter to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

OK this is what it should have been

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open("main.xml", FileMode.Open))
```

Comment: so this means ill change all the ftpStream to stream too?

Comment: it has errors "cannot assign to stream because it is a using variable"

Comment: just noticed you haven't specified where your ftpstream is writting to, so you will need that too, see the edit.

Comment: do i need to right this too? stream = request.GetRequestStream(); because it gving me error, and when I removed it and run your code, still got empty file

Comment: I think I know the problem now, see edit, it was just the using part that wasn't reading the xml

Answer (score 1):

If the file you're writing is always empty, it sounds like you aren't actually getting any of it. The first thing to check would be to see if that `while (contentLength != 0)` is ever entered in the first place.

Update: Also, as John pointed out, the request stream assignment is bad!

Comment: oh i see it really does not enter the while(contentLength != 0), but my file is not empty why is that?